# ¿ Como rellenar un paragrafo HTML con datos en ASP .NET Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net

Tengo una página con un parágrafo y sus estilos en HTML.
Según los datos de un DataSet que tengo previamente rellenado con XML tengo que rellenar unos campos de este parágrafo.

¿ Cual es la mejor manera de hacerlo ?

```
<div class ="paragraph">
  <div class="text">
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> Número ficha: WWWW </span></p>
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> Nombre: XXXX </span></p>
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> Apellido: YYYY </span></p>
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> DNI: ZZZZ </span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Donde `WWWW`, `XXXX`, `YYYY`, `ZZZZ` serian las variables que leo del `DataSet`
Por ejemplo: `WWWW = dataSet.Tables["CLIENTES"].Rows[0]["NumFicha"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, la solución más sencilla es envolver tus valores "WWW", "XXX", "YYY" y "ZZZ" en `spans` (u otro elemento) con un `id` y un `runat="server"` para que sean accesibles desde el servidor y asignarles el valor en el `Page_Load` o donde haga falta.

**Frontal**

```
<p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> Número ficha: <span id="spanWWW" runat="server"></span> </span></p>
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> Nombre: <span id="spanXXX" runat="server"></span> </span></p>
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> Apellido: <span id="spanYYY" runat="server"></span> </span></p>
    <p><span style="font-family:'Arial Negrita'; font-weight:700;"> DNI: <span id="spanZZZ" runat="server"></span> </span></p>
```

**Codebehind (servidor)**

```
spanWWW.InnerHtml = dataSet.Tables["CLIENTES"].Rows[0]["NumFicha"]
```

**Nota**: no sé si tu bloque `HTML` se va a repetir por cada `Row` del `dataSet` pero en ese caso tendrías que iterar por tu `dataSet` para ir asignando valores a cada bloque.

Comment: No se repetirá por cada Row. Quizas lo mejor seria poner todos los datos capturados en una clase. Habia leído algo de que se podía hacer todo el bloque de variables con DataSource para hacer luego un "bind"  que debería usar también ItemTemplate. Pero no se como hacerlo. También he visto otra forma con <%# Eval("NumFicha") %> que no se si es muy correcto hacerlo así o si no tiene nada que ver con lo que digo